# In OnNotify what is the difference between returning TRUE or setting *pResult = TRUE

Tags: c++, mfc, win32com

Given a notification handler

```
BOOL CMyWindow::OnNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pResult)
{
   .......
```

If I process a particular notification. Should I return TRUE or set *pResult = TRUE?

This is something that's bugged me for ages.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1ssc6038(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are quite different things:

- The return value, the `BOOL` indicates whether or not you processed the message. Non-zero if you processed it, zero otherwise. This determines whether or not `DefWindowProc` is called.
- And `pResult` is used to send information back to the caller related to this specific notification. Exactly what that information is depends on which notification is being handled, as specified by the `NMHDR` struct passed via `lParam`.

Comment: So the return value affects whether `DefWindowProc` gets called?

Comment: @BenVoigt That's not clear to me. I'd expect the return value to control whether or not the message is handed on to another party. But I'm not exactly clear on MFC message map routine. Do you know the answer?

Comment: @BenVoigt I dug a bit deeper. You are right. The return value determines whether or not `DefWndProc` is called.